# ngrok: tcp forwarding to 25565 (minecraft server)

Tags: ngrok

When i try to use `./ngrok tcp 25565` the region goes to the default (us) one and it forwards the port (x.xxx.ngrok.io:xxxxx).

So i changed the region to the one closest to my country which is asia so i used the command
`./ngrok tcp -region=ap 25565`. it starts the tcp on the said region but it doesnt forward the port (instead of x.xxx.ngrok.io:xxxxx i get x.xxx.ngrok.io:xx)

[this is what happens when i run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugaje.png)

Im not aware if having a 2 digit port is the same as having a 5 digit port but what i used this on is a minecraft server and the only ip that worked was the (x.xxx.ngrok.io:xxxxx) one.

Comment: Give https://playit.gg a try. It uses an anycast network so your tunnel is live in a lots of different regions all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One guess: your terminal window is a fixed width and it is cutting off the port number.

In particular when you include `region`, the hostname becomes 3 characters longer than the usual: `x.tcp.xx.ngrok.io` vs `x.tcp.ngrok.io`, which fits the fact that you are seeing a port number that is 3 digits shorter than usual.

To get the right address, you have a couple options:

- Check your existing tunnel's address would be to look at ngrok's web inspection interface that runs at `http://localhost:4040`.
- Check the ngrok web dashboard for online tunnels here: `https://dashboard.ngrok.com/endpoints/status`.

Port numbers for ngrok TCP addresses are always 5 digits.